Algorithm for The Ticket to Ride Problem
The Problem
Given a connected graph $G=(V,E)$, edge weights $w:E\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, and a set of vertex pairs $T=\{\{t_{1a},t_{1b}\},\{t_{2a},t_{2b}\},...,\{t_{ka},t_{kb}\}\}|t_{ij}\in V$, find a minimum weight set of edges $E'\subseteq E$ such that for all vertex pairs $\{t_{ia},t_{ib}\}\in T$ there exists a path containing only edges in $E'$ between $t_{ia}$ and $t_{ib}$.
Motivation
In the board game Ticket to Ride, you have a hand of tickets, each with two cities from the map. Your aim is connect the two cities on each ticket in your hand. Every connection on the map requires a certain number of train pieces. I want an algorithm to find the minimum number of train pieces to connect all the tickets in my hand.
Observations

It is not optimal to simply find a minimum weight edge set which connects $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}\{t_{ia},t_{ib}\}$. As a counterexample:



It is not optimal to simply take the union of all shortest $t_{ia}$-$t_{ib}$ paths. As a counterexample:



I suspect this problem is NP-hard, though I didn't know how to prove that.

Attempts to Solve

I first thought I could build the solution iteratively by adding vertex pairs one at a time. So the first step would be find the shortest $t_{1a}$-$t_{1b}$ path. Then, starting with that path, what is the minimum weight edges we can add to connect $t_{2a}$ and $t_{2b}$. And so on until we connect $t_{ka}$ and $t_{kb}$. The problem is that at any step of the algorithm, the previous step could leave us with several components in $E'_{i-1}$ and it is very difficult to determine if it is better to simply union $E'_{i-1}$ and the shortest $t_{ia}$-$t_{ib}$ path, or to try connect one of the components in $E'_{i-1}$ to $t_{ia}$ and $t_{ib}$ at opposite ends of the component. (See observation 2. If we start with A-B-C as one component, it is better to connect F-A and D-C as opposed to adding D-E-F. Even if we figure that out, F-A-B-C-D is still not optimal, proving that this algorithm depends on the order that we process the vertex pairs.)
Another method is to find a minimum weight edge set which connects $\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}\{t_{ia},t_{ib}\}$, then attempt to remove edges which aren't necessary to satisfy the vertex pair connections. The problem is that I couldn't find an algorithm which finds a minimum weight edge set which connects a subset of vertices. Even if I could, I am not sure this algorithm produces an optimal solution for our problem.
Another method is to start with all edges in $E$, then remove edges one at a time (preferring the largest weight edges first) until I can't remove any edges without disconnecting one of vertex pairs. This is not always optimal: it is dependent on the order we remove edges. For example in observation 2, start by removing E-F, we will be forced to remove D-E, but the final solution F-A-B-C-D is not optimal.
A variation on method 3, is to randomize the order of the edges removed (either randomizing the order of tied largest weight edges, or randomizing the edge order entirely). Then I can repeat the process several times with different random orders, and select the best solution.

Questions

What comments do you have for my attempts to solve this problem?
I think that in my attempt 4, if I try every permutation of edges, one of the orders will find an optimal solution. Is that true?
Is there a more efficient algorithm to solve this problem optimally?
Is this problem NP-hard?


That problem is known as the Steiner Forest problem and it is well-studied in the area of network optimization (much before the Ticket to Ride boardgame was published!). Yes, it is NP-hard. As such, there are no known polynomial-time algorithms to solve the problem optimally. In fact, even the easier case when all $t_{ia}$s (but not the $t_{ib}$s, or vice versa) are the same vertex is NP-hard, see Steiner Tree problem or (1).
However, for Steiner Forest an efficient approximation algorithm is known that finds a solution of cost at most twice that of the minimum cost solution (2, 3). The algorithm is not trivial enough to be described here, but it is roughly speaking based on introducing and updating variables for appropriate subsets of vertices of the graph.
References:
For the NP-hardness:
1 Michael R. Garey, David S. Johnson, Computers and Intractability, Problem ND12 in Appendix A. W.H. Freeman, 1979.
For the approximation algorithm:
2 Vijay Vazirani, Approximation Algorithms, Chapter 22. Springer, 2001.
3 David P. Williamson, David B. Shmoys, The Design of Approximation Algorithms, Section 7.4. Cambridge University Press, 2011.
For an experimental comparison of different approaches, see:
4 Laleh Ghalami, Daniel Grosu, Approximation algorithms for Steiner forest: An experimental study, Networks, 79(2):164-188, 2022. Link

Okay, so my 4th attempt would be an approximation algorithm but without any guarantees given. It is probably pretty abysmal compared to the 2-approximation you gave. A 2-approximation isn’t as good as I was hoping for but I see that is the best polynomial approximation we have right now. Is there any information on the expected performance of this algorithm?

My guess is that in practice, if people need to solve this problem accurately, they reformulate it as an Integer Linear Programming problem. That is still NP-hard, but there are highly performing solvers for that. Also, if your graphs are planar, like in Ticket to Ride, there are much (theoretically) better approximation methods, see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5143

I have added a reference on practical performance of the algorithm. I think you should accept my answer now.
